# Instancaite an instance of the child class from the parent

Tags: java, android

First of, sorry for the vague title but I really cannot think how to word this, so please edit in a better title if you think of one.

I have a helper Fragment class (`MasterFragment`), what will never be used as it, it will always be extended, and in it there is this method.

```
public static MasterFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    MasterFragment masterFragment = new MasterFragment();
    masterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return masterFragment;
}
```

When I extend this, lets call the class `ExtendedMasterFragment`, can I make the newInstance method return an instance of `ExtendedMasterFragment` instead of `MasterFragment`?

EDIT: A work around I have is this.

```
public static MasterFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle, MasterFragment masterFragment) {
    masterFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return masterFragment;
}
```

And called like

```
return ListExampleFragment.newInstance(null, new ListExampleFragment());
```

But I'd rather have newInstance work out the class if possible

Comment: You can't *override* the method anyway - it's static.

Comment: Yeah I've just noticed that now, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is overriding the method. Like @JonSkeet said, remove the static so that it's a class member and then override newinstance in ExtendedMasterFragment. There have a separate implementation of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You, absolutely, can have your `newInstance` method return instances of subclasses:

```
public enum Type { THIS, THAT, OTHER; }

public static MasterFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle, Type type) {
    MasterFragment frag;
    switch (type) {
        case THIS: frag = new ThisFrag(); break;
        // ...
    }
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return frag;
}
```

On the other hand, the return *type* of the factory method is MasterFragment.  You will have to cast (ewwwieee) if you need the actual type of the instance.

You can also do this, though it is really, really ugly:

```
public static <T extends MasterFragment> T newInstance(Bundle bundle, Type type) {
    MasterFragment frag;
    switch (type) {
        case THIS: frag = new ThisFrag(); break;
        // ...
    }
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    return (T) frag;  // type conversion warning here.
}
```

If you use the generics, this will work:

```
ThisFrag frag = newInstance(new Bundle(), Type.THIS);
```

Yuk.  Sorry I mentioned it.

Comment: From a little testing the return type actually needs to be MasterFragment (which they all extend from so thats fine), I just need to be able to call in MasterFragment `new WhatEverTheChildClassIs();`, I just can't get that class yet. I've seen getClass(), which looks like it's what I need, except I can't call getClass() from a static context. Whilst I do like this answer, I prefer my work around (See my edit) at the moment as I don't need to edit the MasterFragment class when I extend it.

Comment: Your solution reads a little funny, to me.  It is perfectly reasonable code, though.  I'd just call the method "addArgs" instead of "newInstance".  getClass, on the other hand, is, most definitely *NOT* what you need.

Comment: So do you mean `ExtendedClass ext = new ExtendedClass();ext.setArguments(bundle);`?